# NoClassDefFoundError with LWUIT

Tags: java-me, lwuit

I wrote a J2ME application in Eclipse by using LWUIT. In order to use LWUIT, I had to add `LWUIT.jar` to my project. The project compiles successfully, but could not run, giving a `NoClassDefFoundError` for the `com.sun.lwuit.impl.midp.VKBImplementationFactory` class.

I explored `LWUIT.jar`, and the `VKBImplementationFactory.class` file is present there. I don't get where I went wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I investigated the issue further and I found the answer. See [this EclipseME documentation page](http://eclipseme.org/docs/migration.html).

Comment: Sorry but this is not 24/7 paid service and people answer when they can. Meaning I couldn't see this question because I was at work so no browsing/answering forums. As per your question, you just failed to associate properly external library with your project